# How to create an application-specific config file for TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, configuration-files

I am working on a web application using TypeScript. For some parts of the application, I would like to define a simple configuration file that specifies certain aspects (for example the color palette).

How would I create such a configuration file? In JavaScript, creating `config.js` and referencing it in the HTML code is a very simple solution. What would be the best solution for TypeScript? Maybe a separate `Config.ts` file?

Comment: A separate `config.ts` file seems fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As Typescript is transpiled into JavaScript there is no difference in your usecase.
The browser does not get the TS code but the JS.

Answer (score 60):

You can do it the following way.

First define structure of your config file, in lets say config.ts:

```
export interface Config
{
    uriPath: string;   
    port: number;   
    settings: string[];
}
```

Then create config.json that actually holds the data:

```
{
    "uriPath": "mgNation",
    "port": 1506,
    "settings": [
        "=[tor.start]",
        "=[copp.start]"
    ]
}
```

And consume it in your app.ts:

```
let config: Config = require('./path/to/config.json');
```

Comment: I think that in the interface 'Config', you cannot use the public modifier, it should just be `uriPath: string;` etc. Thanks for the approach though!

Answer (score 0):

I know this is an old thread, but for people arriving here after a Google search (and looking for a full solution), there is the [confinode](https://www.npmjs.com/package/confinode) package which fully manages the configuration file for you.

Comment: I think for people looking for an answer to this, it's not a good idea to resort to a package. I want to know how to do this properly. If I use a package I'm not learning anything